# How to use integration by partial fractions to calculate the integral of a function whose numerator is larger than its denominator?

Tags: calculus, integration

How would you integrate the following function with respect to
$$\int \frac{x^5+x-1}{x^3+1}\;dx$$

Does it make sense to even use partial fractions, or are there other more suitable methods when integrating such functions?

Answer (score 6):

The most surefire way of doing those problems is by doing long division and then getting a remainder (expressed as a fraction). After this, use partial fraction expansion on JUST the remainder part. It should be integrable from there.

Comment: So in the example the integrand becomes $x^2+\frac {-x^2+x-1}{x^3+1}$, then use partial fractions on the second part

Comment: @RossMillikan: I changed the fraction from $\frac{-x^2+x+1}{x^3+1}$ to $\frac{-x^2+x-1}{x^3+1}$. I hope that is okay. I didn't mention that that is also equal to $-\frac1{x+1}$.

Comment: @robjohn:  thanks.  I just wanted to show how the division came out and missed the sign on the 1.